# JS file with imports

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of imports in my html-files and I need those imports on every page.... So I don't want to copy all the imports every time, so I would like to have one file (e.g. .js file) to collect all the needed imports.
With this I just have to import this file and it is easy to maintain.

Is this possible?

Thank YoU!

Comment: script tag will help you do just that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: Are you talking about HTML imports or external scripts?

Comment: What framework do you use? RequireJS can help you or HTML preprocessing in grunt (for instance).

Comment: Simple html with multiple imports of .js and .css files without any framework

Comment: @ChakravarthySM - How should this allimports.html look like? 
I just putted 
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
in it, but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite common. Most people do it for performance reasons - to reduce the number of HTTP requests made for scripts. Look up 'JavaScript concatenation' with regards to whatever build tool you're using - whether that's Maven, Grunt, Gradle, Ant or otherwise.

Comment: I have just multiple html files and multiple .css and .js files. There is no build tool

Answer (score 0):

this might not be relevant, but your question made me go research how to include html files with javascript

this uses jquery, but it still works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
        url: 'yourFile.html',
        dataType: "text/html",
        success: function(){}, // not happening
          error: function(data){
            $("body").html($("body").html() + data.responseText); 
          // use some div instead of body, 
          //depends where u want to append html file
          }
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can load import files using Jquery's $.load() method as

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
     $("head").load("http://www.yourwebsite.com/imports/import.html");
  </script>
 </head>
</body>
</html>
```

and keeping all the imports in import.html as, it will replace the whole head section of original file's, better to put whole head section code in import.html

In Import.html

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```